# Remove a country officially from any marketing communications in different channels

Tags: domains, marketing, best-practices

I got directions from one of my stakeholders to remove any official marketing communication to a certain country, my question is if is it enough to remove the official domain for that country or need to add a set of domains related officially or unofficially to that country? Depends on the country or how to know how to do it right?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on what your stakeholder wants?